# C# auto detect proxy settings

Tags: c#, networking, proxy

C# 2008 SP1

I am using the code to detect if a proxy has been set under "Internet Options". If there is a proxy then I will set this in my webclient.

So I am just checking if the address of the proxy exists. If there is not, then there is no proxy to set in the webclient.

Is this the correct way to do this:

Many thanks for any advice,

```
WebProxy proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();

if (proxy.Address.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proxy URL: " + proxy.Address.ToString());
    wc.Proxy = proxy;
}
```

====== Code edit ======

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(ref InternetConnectionState_e lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

[Flags]
enum InternetConnectionState_e : int
{
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM = 0x1,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN = 0x2,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY = 0x4,
    INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED = 0x10,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE = 0x20,
    INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED = 0x40
}     

// Return true or false if connecting through a proxy server
public bool connectingThroughProxy()
{
    InternetConnectionState_e flags = 0;
    InternetGetConnectedState(ref flags, 0);
    bool hasProxy = false;

    if ((flags & InternetConnectionState_e.INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY) != 0)
    {
        hasProxy = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hasProxy = false;
    }

    return hasProxy;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears that [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) is the [official replacement](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Jul/11/Replacing-deprecated-SystemNetWebProxyGetDefaultProxy-in-NET-20) for WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy.

You should be able to drop that in to your original code with only a little modification. Something like:

```
WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy) WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
if (proxy.Address.AbsoluteUri != string.Empty)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proxy URL: " + proxy.Address.AbsoluteUri);
    wc.Proxy = proxy;
}
```

Comment: This is the recommended approach, and it insulates you against having to write a bunch of other code.

Comment: I've found that this gives me a class cast exception as WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy is returning a WebProxyWrapper. Unfortunately, in my case, WebProxyWrapper gives me no access to the underlying WebProxy object, which is frustrating as it seems the code I'm trying to debug is not applying the proxy in the live environment but is doing so in the development environment.

Comment: I have the same problem. I managed to obtain web proxy's URI instead using: **Uri uriProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http:// someserver.com"));**

Comment: the cast you provided actually throws an InvalidCastException! Unable to cast object of type 'WebProxyWrapper' to type 'System.Net.WebProxy'.

Comment: invalidcastexception

Answer (score 5):

First, [GetDefaultProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.getdefaultproxy.aspx) is marked as deprecated so you have no guarantee it will be around in even the immediate future.  Second, [Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.address.aspx) can be null so the code you gave risks a NullReferenceException:

Answer (score 5):

`WebClient` etc use the WinHTTP settings (not the IE settings), so the easiest thing to do is to configure WinHTTP! On XP etc you can use:

```
proxycfg -u
```

to import the current IE settings into the WinHTTP store. After that, `WebClient` etc should be able to use the same settings without issue. On Vista and Windows 7 this is now found under:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy ie
```

You need to run this as administrator.

Comment: I have edited my code by using a p/invoke. This works well telling me if the computing is connecting through a proxy. However, referencing my initial code post. Is this the correct way to get the information about the proxy. i.e. address, port? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I still maintain that configuring WinHTTP is a better option than querying it yourself. At work, all the (non-local) traffic goes via a proxy, and I've never had a problem just using `WebClient` if I've configured WinHTTP first.

Comment: The problem with this solution is it requires the user to run a command changing system wide settings just to use your application. Under a restricted environment they also may not have access to the command and/or your application may not have access to it.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your first sentence is correct. It depends on the configuration of the application. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx for more information.

Comment: @EricLaw I'd have to check, but that was the behaviour I saw repeatedly on vanilla desktops with standard (empty) app config. I might be misremembering though.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
        var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        Uri testUrl = new Uri("http://proxy.example.com");
        var proxyUrl = proxy.GetProxy(testUrl);
        if (proxyUrl != testUrl)
            //Use your proxy here
        else
            //We are not using a proxy
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
  <proxy/>
  <bypasslist/>
  <module/>
</defaultProxy>
```

Use this snippet in application.config file.

Comment: +1. This worked for me.  Enabled tracing to identify the failure (can't retrieve proxy settings for uri).  Then, the default proxy (set by domain policy to an invalid uri) was being used and instantly failing.  I used the above settings and boom.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
public string GetMeMyInfo(string searchCriteria)
{
    // Instatiate the web service and declare the necessary variables
    WsService.WsServiceBus oWsGetInfo = new WsService.WsServiceBus();
    // Configure the Web Service Proxy
    oWsGetInfo.Proxy = System.Net.WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
    oWsGetInfo.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    // Invoke the web service
    return oWsGetInfo.GetInfo4Me(searchCriteria);
}
```

That will get the default proxy setting and credentials before invoking your web service for example.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the System.Net.Configuration.ProxyElement class.  That may have info you're looking for.

What you describe works, you can also look in the registry.

Here's a powershell script I wrote to check out the proxy:

```
function get-proxy
{
    $path = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
    $reg = get-itemproperty $path
    return $reg
}
```

Comment: I think it was not mentioned that within that registry key path, the fields/keys of interest are "ProxyEnable" and "ProxyServer"

Answer (score 2):

Setting my request proxy to `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` solved the problem.

`WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` is the actual way but it is now deprecated.