# Get proxy from IE lan settings in C#

Tags: c#, networking, proxy

I want to progrmatically(C#)  get the proxy that is set in "IE -> Lan Settings" and i used the following code from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844467/c-sharp-auto-detect-proxy-settings)

```
WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy) WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

but the problem is that I get the following exception:-

> Cannot cast 'System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy' (which has an
>   actual type of 'System.Net.WebRequest.WebProxyWrapper') to
>   'System.Net.WebProxy'

So how do I get the WebProxy object so that I can check if the proxy is set or not?

EDIT :

I got it work ; i just had to know if a specific url was bypasssed or not so i did this

```
Uri rpkgURI = new Uri("%url%", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
bool isBypass;
if (webProxy != null)
{
 isBypass = webProxy.IsBypassed(rpkgURI);
}
else
{
 isBypass = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to cast it to a `WebProxy` object?  Many implementations that accept a proxy now take an `IWebProxy`, and the `DefaultWebProxy` implements `IWebProxy`.

For example:

```
IWebProxy proxy2 = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = proxy2;
```

Or even more succintly:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```