# Capturing event of Windows LAN proxy settings change?

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, lan

Is there a way to capture event for a LAN Proxy settings change in C# program/service? I would like to capture event when the user enables or disables the LAN proxy server or changes the address or the port of the proxy server.

I already tested with NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler but it doesn't seem to capture this event.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844467/c-sharp-auto-detect-proxy-settings

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to listen events from Windows Registry (including change of Registry value) but apparently the Registry value of Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings is not being changed when the user changes the LAN proxy settings.